# Blank page on Laravel Eloquent update

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this code:

```
DB::table('users')->update(array('marked_for_deletion' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'ready_for_deletion' => 1));
```

The instruction does it's job, but here my page stops and returns a blank page, even though I have more instructions bellow. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide more code and context, this way we can help you better. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: provide full code please

Comment: return something right after your update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the correct way update using db facade

```
DB::update('update users set marked_for_deletion = ? , ready_for_deletion = ?',array(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 1));
```

or if you want do `update` your way u must set `where` condition

```
DB::table('users')->where('id',1)->update(array('marked_for_deletion' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), 'ready_for_deletion' => 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT.
I did something like this:

```
DB::update("UPDATE db_asm.users
                    SET marked_for_deletion = NOW(),
                        ready_for_deletion = 1");
```